# War Card Game for python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a war card game, but I am having difficulties getting my code to connect.  I keep getting the error that deck1 isn't defined.  I cannot see why this is happening. I am trying to connect the deck1 and deck2 to the playerA=deck1.pop and so forth.  Thanks for the help!

```
import random
total = {
   'winA':0,
   'winB':0
}

def shuffleDeck():
    suits = {'\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663'}
    ranks = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'}
    deck = []

for suit in suits:
    for rank in ranks:
        deck.append(rank+' '+suit)

random.shuffle(deck)
return deck

def dealDecks(deck):
    deck1 = deck[:26]
    deck2= deck[26:]
    hand = []
    return hand

def total(hand):
    values = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '1':10,
          'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13,'A':14}

def war(playerA, playerB):
    if playerA==playerB:
        print("Tie")
    elif playerA > playerB:
        print("Winner:Player A")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Winner:player B")
        return -1

def process_game(playerA,playerB):
    result = game(p1c,p2c)
    if result == -1:
        total['winB'] += 1
    else:
        total['winA'] += 1

deck = shuffleDeck()

dealDecks(deck);

gameplay = input("Ready to play a round: ")

while gameplay == 'y':

    playerA = deck1.pop(random.choice(deck1))
    playerB = deck2.pop(random.choice(deck2))
    print("Player A: {}. \nPlayer B: {}. \n".format(playerA,playerB))
    gameplay = input("Ready to play a round: ")

if total['winA'] > total['winB']:
    print("PlayerA won overall with a total of {} wins".format(total['winA']))
else:
    print("PlayerB won overall with a total of {} wins".format(total['winB']))
```

Comment: `deck1` is only defined inside `dealDecks()`. You can't access it outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `dealDecks` doesn't really do what it says it does. Why does it create and `return` an empty list:

```
def dealDecks(deck):
    deck1 = deck[:26]
    deck2= deck[26:]
    hand = []
    return hand
```

that is then ignored:

```
dealDecks(deck);
```

Thus `deck1` is inaccessible anywhere outside `dealDecks`. Instead, actually return and assign the two halves of the deck:

```
def split_deck(deck):
    middle = len(deck) // 2
    deck1 = deck[:middle]
    deck2 = deck[middle:]
    return deck1, deck2

deck1, deck2 = split_deck(deck)
```

Note that I've factored out the "magic number", renamed the function to describe what it does and adopted `lowercase_with_underscores` per the [Python style guide (PEP-0008)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).

Comment: Thanks! But now I get this error and I don't know exactly what it means...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\homework8.py", line 56, in <module>
    playerA = deck1.pop(random.choice(deck1))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>

Comment: The error *tells you* exactly what it means. Try reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: I am now getting an error like this...Ready to play a round: n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\homework8.py", line 62, in <module>
    if total['winA'] > total['winB']:
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable (Am I missing something?)

Comment: Yes, you are; much of your code makes no sense. Many issues are similar to the one I have solved for you, because you aren't using functions and variables correctly. I suggest you read through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Python creates variables on demand. Because of this, in your `dealDecks` function, instead of referencing the global variables `deck1` and `deck2` it instead creates two local variables of the same name.

Thus, when you try to `pop` off of the global `deck1` it errors because it never was defined.

To fix this, you **COULD** use the `global` key word in `dealDecks`:

```
def dealDecks():
    global deck1
    global deck2
```

However, this is not good practice. You should only use `global` if its **absolutely necessary**. Typically good classes and program structure removes the need for `global`.

Comment: Why have you suggested an implementation then immediately pointed out that the OP shouldn't adopt it?

Comment: Mainly because my actual suggestions would have required a bigger refactoring of the code than is appropriate here on SO. So I offered a quick solution to their problem, though I do like your refactor more than mine.